# When should I save push token to my server in Android?

Tags: push-notification, react-native, expo

My app has a little dialog where users can click to opt-in for push notifications. On iOS when they press this, they get the permission request and then if they approve it, I send a POST request to my server with their push tokens.

Since, Android remote notification permissions are granted during the app installation, when do I send this POST request to my server with their push tokens?

Answer (score 0):

Save it on first launch.
Using AsyncStorage you can save user first launch and save the token at this time

Comment: I thought about that but storing a first launch value via AsyncStorage seem quite heavy duty.

Comment: Maybe. But I don’t believe so. Another way would probably be checking the database if user saved a token yet. I think this would be more cumbersome